# How does Istio compare to Traefik?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio

[Traefik](https://traefik.io/) is a reverse HTTP proxy with several supported backends, Kubernetes included. How does Istio compare?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, the link is not found

Comment: https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's something of an apples-to-oranges comparison.

Edge proxies like Traefik or Nginx are best compared to [Envoy](https://lyft.github.io/envoy/) - the proxy that Istio leverages. An Envoy proxy is installed automatically by Istio adjacent to every pod.

Istio provides several higher level capabilities beyond Envoy, including routing, ACLing and service discovery and access policy *across a set* of services. In effect, it stitches a set of Envoy enabled services together. This design pattern is often called a *service mesh*.

Istio is also currently limited to Kubernetes deployments in a single cluster, though work is in place to remove these restrictions in time.

Comment: It seems Istio covers them all but with the overhead cost. https://www.datacenterknowledge.com/devops/istio-v-linkerd-former-may-be-more-service-mesh-you-need

Comment: Istio deploys to multiple clusters nowadays. https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/

Comment: Now with [Traefik Mesh](https://traefik.io/traefik-mesh/) it becomes fair comparison again: Traefik Proxy compares to Envoy, and Traefik Mesh compares to Istio.

Answer (score 10):

As Mark O'Connor responded, Istio is not just a load balancer or reverse proxy for K8S. Its a full microservice mesh, for inter-microservice communication as well as API management at the edge, with extensive support for monitoring and security (authn/authz). Please take a look at [here](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/) for more information.